# How to use pandas within snakemake pipelines

Tags: python, pandas, pipeline, snakemake, directed-acyclic-graphs

I would like to improve the reproducibility of some python codes I made by transforming some codes into a data pipeline. I am used to `targets` in `R` and would like to find an equivalent in `Python`. I have the impression that `snakemake` is quite close to that.

I don't understand how we can use `pandas` to import an input in a `snakemake` task, modify it and then write `output`.

Let's take the easiest pipeline I can think of: we take a csv and write a copy somewhere else.

The pipeline works fine when using bash script:

```py
rule trying_snakemake:
    input:
        path="untitled.txt"
    output:
        "test-snakemake.csv"
    run:
        shell("cp {input.path} {output}")
```

I wanted to use the equivalent approach with `pandas` (of course here using `pandas` does not seem necessary but this is to understand the logic):

```py
rule trying_snakemake:
    input:
        path="untitled.txt"
    output:
        "test-snakemake.csv"
    run:
        import pandas as pd
        df = pd.read_csv({input.path})
        df.to_csv({output}, header=False)
```

```sh
snakemake -c1
```

```
Invalid file path or buffer object type: <class 'set'>
  File "/home/jovyan/work/label-openfood/Snakefile", line 19, in __rule_trying_snakemake
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py", line 311, in wrapper
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers/readers.py", line 586, in read_csv
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers/readers.py", line 482, in _read
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers/readers.py", line 811, in __init__
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers/readers.py", line 1040, in _make_engine
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers/c_parser_wrapper.py", line 51, in __init__
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers/base_parser.py", line 222, in _open_handles
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/common.py", line 609, in get_handle
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/common.py", line 396, in _get_filepath_or_buffer
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.9/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 52, in run
Exiting because a job execution failed. Look above for error message
```

I think the error comes at the `read_csv` step but I don't understand what it means (I am used to situations where `pandas` works like a charm)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are very close, the curly braces are not needed within `run` directive:

```py
rule trying_snakemake:
    input:
        path="untitled.txt"
    output:
        csv="test-snakemake.csv"
    run:
        import pandas as pd
        df = pd.read_csv(input.path)
        df.to_csv(output.csv, header=False)
```

Comment: worked like a charm thanks ! (I had not understand the subtility of the braces)

Comment: Yes, those are definitely needed for `shell` (snakemake does some `.format` substitutions on the final shell command, so they need to be in curly brackets).